# HibernateItemReaderHelper from release 3.0.7 does not work with Hibernate 5.2.x

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-batch

I am writing a batch with Springboot and it uses HibernateItemReaderHelper during the read phase. I also have in my depencies a dependecy with hibernate 5.2.x. During the execution I get the following error:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.hibernate.StatelessSession.createQuery(Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/hibernate/Query;

Im surprissed because in Maven repository this is the last version and it has no compatibility with Hibernate 5.1 or superior, because it does not return an Object of the class org.hibernate.query.Query, instead org.hibernate.Query.

Im missing something in order to use Spring Batch and Hibernate 5.2 ??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

SpringBatch 3.x does not support Hibernate 5.x.  You'll need to upgrade to Spring Batch 4 to get that support.

Answer (score 0):

As Michael said, with Version 4.0.0 or higher should work. With Spring boot in my case the problem is that the Spring Batch 4.0.0 is not in the standart Maven repository. Adding the Alfresco repository solved my problem.

```
<repositories>
      <repository>
        <id>Alfresco Public</id>
        <url>https://artifacts.alfresco.com/nexus/content/repositories/public/</url>
      </repository>
</repositories>
```